# Demons come from another planet instead of "Hell". How would this affect human's beliefs, mythology?

Tags: magic, religion, mythology

I want demons to appear in my story, but having them originate from Hell was never appealing. Anyways, these "demons" are summoned to Earth- a planet that's only just discovering magic.

They are- in essence- still demons. Things like holy trinkets and devil's traps still work on them. But *what about* Hell? I'm not very sure how else to put it.

I could probably get away with not touching on this at all in my story- humans never learn the truth (aside from main characters) about the demons' origin & just assume they came from Hell. But some deeper world building couldn't hurt.

**EDIT:** To get a better idea of the tone- humor is really important to me. I draw a lot of inspiration from things like Kill la Kill and One Punch. Sensible nonsense.
That said, Yes: I'm comparing a world where demons come from a planet *vs* a world where demons come from hell. However, this Earth has never encountered real demons until their discovery of magic.

Comment: So you want to have a "believable enough" explanations for why Judeo-Christian style demons exist, but without a place like hell? What does a proper answer for this look like?

Comment: A friend suggested that I borrow from "planes" in D&D. Ex: The Plane of Torment could pass as their Hell. I have been borrowing a lot of material from that and Baldur's Gate though ): I'm starting to feel unoriginal

Comment: The mere presence of supernatural beings would drastically change our world's beliefs.  How could you doubt people have souls when "demons" can always tell if you have one and offer to trade you for it.  It would change our understanding of science that creatures can be summoned from 100's of light-years in minutes and be repelled by pieces of wood at 90 degree angles.

Comment: @vsock do you mean how the modern world would change, or a classical medieval or a fantasy world.  If the last could you add more details of the original belief system.

Comment: Are you comparing a world where demons come from a planet vs a world where demons come from hell, or are you comparing a world where demons come from a planet vs a world where there is no particular scientific evidence that demons exist?  The latter case could be a "completely different" answer, changing absolutely every single bit of beliefs/mythology from the ground up.

Comment: Have you seen Robert Aspirin's *myth* series?

Comment: (I don't have enough reputation to post a Comment, so here's an Answer) Raymond E. Feist does this in his Riftwar Cycle. There is a planet of demons that's being destroyed, forcing them to claim other planets with the help of portals.

Comment: Every answer seems to be ignoring the little bombshell about humans in your world discovering magic. How does your magic work? Do the demons act exactly like demons in religion do? Why are demons affected by holy trinkets and traps? Are religious beliefs true and verifiable through science? If yes, the most likely answer is that religion will take over and atheism will be treated as a mental illness.

Comment: What are "holy trinkets and devil's traps" and how exactly do they work on "them"?

Comment: Wait! You telling me that *our* demons aren't actually alien's?! That they really are from 'hell'? I'm pretty sure you could explain demons as alien's, with the ignorant common folk making up strange and mysterious stories for their 'unknown' origins! Sort of how our ancestors used to think birds flew to another world,or some similar nonsense, when they migrated. Until one year, they saw an arrow in a returning bird and realised they flew to another land on this planet ... Africa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Demons coming from another planet prove doesn't prove or disproved hell, heaven and the afterlife. It only proves demon-like creatures do exist, and there's a place whence they come.

Religious texts and mythology are mostly figurative, sometimes partly based on truth. Maybe the truth here is that aliens visited Earth once, and they really weren't nice guys, and then they went on their merry way because "meh, not hellish enough, 2/10, would not raid again" or something.

Here hell would be figurative for "wherever these things came from, which must be a really bad place". The guys who wrote the Bible never saw hell, nor did the Greeks. It just serves to tell you "don't sin", or more generally "be nice", otherwise hell awaits.

If religion is prevalent, then demons coming to Earth would support claims that sinning is really bad and unleashes the apocalypse. So that would likely make religious power even more powerful because people like salvation.

If religion isn't prevalent, it may not change much. If we're advanced enough to fathom life on other planets and interplanetary travel, we'll probably assume that demons where created after these things. In any case, it might sparkle interest in religion, though whether people will take it at face value or not is hard to guess.

Answer (score 9):

I actually am writing a book that is very similar (more than just demons though).

1. All of a sudden "Demons" become synonymous with Aliens.
2. This would both support and destroy Christianity and Islam. (Judaism would be mostly unaltered, they didn't care that much about demons in the first place.)
3. On the plus side for them, the religions get to say, for once, "See, we weren't making it up!" But on the flip side, the religious becomes mundane. Demons weren't some "strange mystical force" but just aliens that our ancestors misunderstood. They aren't as powerful in concept. That in turn throws other myths of the religion into a similar light. Maybe Angels/God etc. are real, but also just as subject to the laws of reality as well.
4. This results in another interesting spin... religion changes from being a "source of moral guidance of an unseen hand" and into "being a source of intel on alien species". Prophecies become less viewed as the fate of the universe and more as alien battle plans.
5. Religion loses it's "mystical" interpretation and their claims begin to be taken deadly seriously and treated as such. Clergy (Christian, Islam, Devil Worshipping) all become viewed as infiltrating agents of an alien empire. Instead of being "holy men" or similar, they would be viewed by society the same way that the US viewed communist public speakers.
6. It'd probably mean the end of organized religion... at least of Christianity and Islam.

Answer (score 2):

## 1- Hell might refer to hellish planets

So demons *do* descend from hell(s). But hell is just a name for terrible, terrible planets such as [tres-2B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrES-2b), [Bellerophon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/51_Pegasi_b), [Osiris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HD_209458_b) or some other mind-blowingly horrible planet.

## 2- Religions would be studied in deep detail

Abrahamic religions (Islam, Christianity, judaism) would be studied with in great detail and many of the brightest minds would endeavor to *decode* the scientific and astronomical information present in them.

## 3- Old demonic myths will be studied for rewriting human history

Ancient tales and legends about demons, ghosts and such would be studied in detail to figure out how long aliens have been visiting Earth, what are their probable motives and how much damage they have caused thus far.

Comment: I take offense at this, TrES-2b is a wonderful planet

Comment: :O don't frighten me!! @TrEs-2b

Answer (score 1):

### **Holy Book**

The Bible was written thousands of years ago, and it's a common theory that some major parts were easily lost in translation over many different iterations. Imagine a primitive human in your world, before discovering magic, or even basic technology, meeting an alien or many aliens (monstrous and/or intelligent). This encounter changes society based on the actions the alien(s) chose (did they cast judgement, did they murder indiscriminately?) and it becomes associated with a spiritual movement. A human writes a book to try to rationalize this encounter and passes it down through the ages without knowing from where the alien(s) came from. Maybe as the book becomes a pillar for modern society, some of the finer details are lost and the entire encounter sounds like spiritual metaphor. The stories would change to reflect the nature of the encounter, plus any bias/creative input from the person writing it. I don't see it actually impacting beliefs until Demons have their "Second Coming".

### **Demon Wards = Accidental Anti-Alien Materials**

The ancient alien encounter was extremely violent, but the humans of the time found ways to stop the attacks and passed these methods down through the Holy Scripture. When the demons come back, you find out Holy Water is only considered Holy because water and other materials wards are made out of are highly corrosive to demon skin. Old hymns are intentional arrangements of frequencies that scramble demon brains. There can be magic involved as well, but having Hell be a planet means Earth is not the ideal living environment for Demons. Maybe the Demons have come back with protection from these wards and traps as well.

### **Sunday School = Boot Camp**

Demons invade and people start trying out the methods laid out in their Holy Books since the "Demons" look remarkably similar to ancient art and depictions. As soon as it's established that there's a correlation between a particular religion's depiction and the currently invading demons, that's when society will drastically change. Masses will convert and consider the religion as training. Skeptics will rise as well while the chaos unfolds, but the more evidence a given faith receives, the more it will reach a higher prominence. Everybody's waiting for a sign, right? And when shit hits the fan and the Pope is showing how their methods are right and will actually protect you, the more followers they'll accrue. This could lead to wars between similar religions over who's "more right". You'll have people fighting demons and questioning their faith and each other.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it have much of impact on religion at all, or at least it won't impact what people believe about religion.

Atheist well say that since hell is a physical place then the demons or not the forces of evil but just a strange alien.

None atheist people will point to the demons aversion to holy symbols, devil traps and the scripture, they will say that this show that there a more to the demons are more then just aliens but have some sort of spiritual aspect to them.

But weather you believe there are aliens or demons all will agree that the scripture will be studied for information. In addition to this the Jews and Muslim writes about demons will also be studied. That doesn't mean of course that everyone will except everything in there as truth (at least not at first) but they would be a factor in forming plans on how to fight the demons.